# Error in executing jquery function

Tags: jquery, html

I am executing following code but i am getting error: "Objected Expected"
I checked the code but didnt find any problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                 $("#clickme").click(function(){
                     $("#body1").load("http://www.w3schools.com");
                 });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <a href="#" id="#clickme">Click me</a>
            hello
                   </div>
        <div id="body1">
            mid

        </div>
        <div id="footer">
                    hi
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your id should be

```
<a href="#" id="clickme">Click me</a>
```

There was a `#` in your id.

** EDIT **
Your other problem is that you can't load a page on another domain into your site. You'll have to use an iframe for that.

Comment: still its not loading. I am using IE8 :(

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the hash sign from the id of clickme

```
<a href="#" id="clickme">Click me</a>
```